# Change of direction in relation to Arrow

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am new to programming and would like to know how do I create an exchange system similar to that used in the game meaning that link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11PXll2K_rg&list=FLdeibbADKB476CmvWIyd21A&index=2

I want to know how my pump recognize the position of the arrow and start moving in her direction:

I thought I'd start doing this:

code used in the object that is in motion:

```
public float speed;
public int direction;

void Start () {
    direction = 1;
}


void Update () {

    if (gameObject.transform.position == GameObject.Find("ArrowUp").transform.position){

        direction = 1;
    }

    if (transform.position ==  GameObject.Find("ArrowDown").transform.position)){

        direction = 2;
    }


        if(direction == 1){
          transform.position += new Vector3(0,speed*Time.deltaTime,0);
         }
        if(direction == 2 ){
          transform.position += new Vector3(0,-(speed*Time.deltaTime),0);
         }

    }}
```

Type: I have a bomb going object moving toward the object that contains the arrow, Vector3 their positions X and Z are the same, the position is different in Y.

Arrow in position (0,10,0)

initial position of the pump (0,0,0)

the void start with this direction = 1, then the object moves up

then when the pump reaches the position (0,10,0), I want it to recognize that this same position in the Down Arrow then wanted to pump mudaçe direction = 2, then so would move down.

noting, that the arrow rotates 90 degrees at a time interval. so then the direction of motion would be different.

question: do I want to know how to recognize that this pump in the same position of the object arrow and then give the order to change its movement;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "Arrows" are oriented to Y Axis (green arrow), you can use transform.up

```
void Update () {

Vector3 ArrowUpPosition = GameObject.Find("ArrowUp").transform.position
Vector3 ArrowDownPosition = GameObject.Find("ArrowDown").transform.position

if (gameObject.transform.position == ArrowUpPosition ){

    direction = 1;
}

if (transform.position ==  ArrowDownPosition )){

    direction = 2;
}

if(direction == 1){
    transform.position += ArrowUpPosition.transform.up * speed*Time.deltaTime;
}
if(direction == 2 ){
    transform.position += ArrowDownPosition.transform.up * speed*Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use transform.right or transform.forward ( and -transform.forward, -transform.up, -transform.right)

### For performance!!! :

AVOID GAMEOBJECT.FIND IN UPDATE: Get reference in Start()

AVOID GAMEOBJECT.FIND AT : Pass gameobjects to the script as fields, if you can.

AVOID THIS ISTRUCTIONS IN UPDATE: Do they in OnTriggerStay, if gameobjects have trigger colliders.

Comment: Thanks, however, has not managed to make my object pump recognize this in the same position of the "arrow". the only thing I want is to recognize that this pump in the same position of the object "arrow" 

when I use:if (transform.position.y >=  GameObject.Find("ArrowDown").transform.position.y )){

    direction = 2;
}  : the pump recognizes,,,, use == but when she did not know

Comment: Ah, ok. 

maybe a precision problem. == implies that 2 vector3 matches exacly.
You may use:  `if ((vector1 - vector2).sqrMagnitude < smallFloat) { do actions... } `